# Why can't I terminate Sinatra server?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Why can't I stop Sinatra server using the following:

```
post '/terminate' do
  Thread.current.kill
end
```

I type in my browser:

```
localhost:<port>/terminate
```

but it never terminates the server, Sinatra says that it does not know such path. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adzdavies is partially right, you don't hit the route because your browser is issuing a `GET` request and you've defined a `post` route, but `exit` won't work either, it'll just spit out an error at you. As will raising an `Interrupt` exception. `Thread.current.kill` just ends execution of the current thread, which seems to mean killing the current instance and the server [will just spawn a new instance on the next request](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Request/Instance%20Scope), it won't kill the server, the server has its own process.

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class SillyWaysToKillTheServer < Sinatra::Base

  enable :inline_templates

  get "/" do
    erb :index
  end

  get '/terminate' do
    exit # system exit!
  end

  get "/threadkill" do
    Thread.current.kill
  end

  get "/exception" do
    raise Interrupt, "Kill the server, please!"
  end

  run! if __FILE__ == $0
end

__END__

@@ layout
<html>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>

@@ index

<p><a href="/terminate">terminate</a></p>
<p><a href="/threadkill">threadkill</a></p>
<p><a href="/exception">exception</a></p>
```

Sinatra is a framework, not a server. The server has its own process and runs a little loop that starts new threads or forks (Thin uses threading as its model, Unicorn uses preforking, for example) or whatever which run the Sinatra code you've provided. To stop the *server*, either use Ctrl+c to interrupt it, or find the process number and use `kill` or send a SIGHUP via something *like everyone else does*. There may be some good reason for doing stopping a webserver like this, but I can't think of one, and maybe different servers would respond differently to the Thread kills and exits etc, but they still won't stop your server.

Go with the flow.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will be doing a "GET" http request.

If you change to

```
get '/terminate' do
  exit # system exit!
end
```

I think it will work.